# My biquad filter implementation is unstable

Tags: delphi, filter

I am attempting to implement a biquad peak filter in the audio range using the Direct 2 Transposed configuration.  I believe my 'a' and 'b' parameters are correct because they correspond to those generated by EarLevel Engineering Biquad Calculator v3 (https://www.earlevel.com/main/2021/09/02/biquad-calculator-v3/).  Below is my code processing the difference equations (Please ignore FType 1 and 3).  SignalIn is a 440 Hz sine wave.  Calculations use the Double data type.

```
function TFrmFilters.Filter(SignalIn: double; FType: integer): double;
begin
  case FType of
    1:                             // AllPass (no filter)
      Result := SignalIn;
    2:                             // Biquad Peak
    begin
      Yn := SignalIn + S1n_1;
      S1n := S2n_1 + b1 * SignalIn - a1 * Yn;
      S2n := b2 * SignalIn - a2 * Yn;
      S1n_1 := S1n;
      S2n_1 := S2n;
      Result := Yn;
    end;
    3:                             // Resonator  (not implemented)
      Result := SignalIn;
  end;
end;
```

Filter exhibited instability over wide ranges of Gain, Q and SignalIn frequency.  I seem to have a problem with my handling of the difference equations.

Comment: Too many variables from outside the code shown to make any sense of this.

Answer (score 1):

I had inadvertently interchanged the 'a' and 'b' parameters.  This seems to be the case with some of the cookbook filter solutions on the net.

I apologize for submitting a question prior to doing sufficient research.

Comment: For completeness, post the corrected code in this answer.